# How to check all details of in app purchase item

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In my app, I have implemented `INAPP PURCHASE`. so i want to know details of the INAPP PURCHASE of my app. i want to generate the list of inAPP purchase billing.

Thanks

Comment: log in to iTunesConnect

Comment: @Paulw11 and next step ??